# Is there a R function equivalent to Python's split()?

Tags: r

I am trying to enter to create a R program which will accept multiple inputs from users separated by space. For python, I was using the split function but I don't know any equivalent function for r.

```
while (i<=n){
 cf[i]=as.double(readline(prompt='Enter cashflow:'))
 p[i]=as.double(readline(prompt='Enter corresponding probability:'))
 e[i]=cf[i]*p[i]
 cat('\014')
 i=i+1
```

}

Currently, I am using the loops but the typing process is tedious.

Comment: Did you look at `?str_split`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `strsplit` to split string and `as.numeric` to convert to numbers

```r
# read input, value is stored as a string
cf = readline(prompt='Enter cashflow:')
pr = readline(prompt='Enter corresponding probability:')

# split on ' ', unlist list-of-list, then convert to numeric
cf = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(cf, ' ')))
pr = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(pr, ' ')))

e = cf*pr
```

Comment: Unlist before converting then we don't need lapply: `c = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(c, ' ')))`, also, avoid function names as variables: `c`

Comment: @zx8754 Thanks. That's efficient and better. I have updated to code.